# jQuery, How to detect PHP post/get variables?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

In a PHP, there's a form that sends a variable to the same page. 
I want to make a jQuery that shows/hides a specific div (using ID); if the value is sent (the form is sent to the same page), I want to show the div

in the PHP file, I have this form:

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="12345">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

in the linked js file, 
How can I detect the hidden value "status" is sent? and if the $_GET["status"] is not NULL,
I want to show $('specificID').show();, which was originally:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('#specificID').hide();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to embed your JS in your PHP like this:

```
<?php
    some php...
?>

some markup...

$(document).ready(function (){

<?php
    if($_GET["status"]):
?>
    $('#specificID').show();
<?php
    else:
?>
    $('#specificID').hide();
<?php
    endif;
?>

});
...
```

Comment: This code shows #specificID only after when the page is reloaded. It disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET["varname"]

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/form.html